# System.Text.Json Object Cycle Only Include the Levels Specified

Tags: asp.net, json, api, asp.net-core

I have some complex objects that create a self referencing loop because I use includes in my queries, like so:

```
await context.Users.Include(x => x.Location).ToListAsync();
```

I am aware that I can work around this issue by the following line of code in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

However, I don't want to take that approach because the json returned contains like 10 levels since I have a lot of navigation properties. I don't want all of those levels included in my json. I just want the ones that I specified with the `include`. So in the example from above, I only want the `Location` object to appear in the User object. However, since my `Location`object contains a list of `User` object, it will also contain that backwards reference which I am not interested in. Does someone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) which don't contain the navigation properties that create the cycle. You can map them using tools like AutoMapper. I am leaving the question open for better solutions which automatically only contain the level which you specified by the `include`.